# Получение слова из выражения

Tags: c++, строки

Делаю свой калькулятор-компилятор в свой байт-код на C++ как на более производительном, чем Java. Дело дошло до превращения строки в лексемы или как их называют по-другому токены. То есть строка "(var1 + var2) * var3" должна превратиться в `tokens[left_bracket, var var1, operator_plus, var var2, right_bracket, operator_multiplication, var var3]`
'Код' массива tokens состоит из наследников класс Token.
Для этого нужна функция `string getStatement(string str, int statement_position)` которая возвращает строку в которой содержится слово.

Надо получить слово от пробела до пробела.
Пример : `getStatement("int variable_a = variable_b + variable_c", 8);` должна вернуть `variable_a`.

Comment: Все дополнения к вопросу должны быть в самом вопросе, а не в комментариях (нажмите "править" под вопросом, и внесите код в сам вопрос).

Comment: "калькулятор-компилятор, байт-код на C++" что ни слово, то загадка. А по теме, слишком прямолинейный ваш мозг - в данном случае split(), но на все готовых функций не наберешься. нужен алгоритм. вроде конечного автомата. как минимум.

Comment: Подобную штуку я делал на Java, на C++ у меня нет опыта разработки .